# How do you set up a Fossil SCM server on OSX

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server

I'd like to run the [Fossil SCM](http://fossil-scm.org/) as a service that is called when needed on my Mac Mini Server. How should I go about configuring this?

Comment: Yes, I answered my own question, but I thought this might save someone else some work looking for the answers.

Comment: could someone add fossil-scm as a tag - if you feel it is appropriate - I don't have the rep.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the Fossil SCM setup as a server on Mac OS X.

This works on 10.7, but should work back to 10.4 AFAIK.

Pre-requistites:

- fossil binary somewhere on your system (I used ~/bin/fossil )
- a fossil repository (or repositories) in a folder (I used ~/fossil-repository )

The steps:

- put the org.fossil-scm.service.plist file(below) in /Library/LaunchDaemons
- change references to '/Users/spdegabrielle/'( ~/ ) to your own path
- open Terminal and type the following:

  > sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.fossil-scm.service.plist
- open your browser to http://localhost:8081/reponame (I used 'projects' the name of my main repository as the default repository)

For more info, check Creating Launch Daemons and Agents.

[org.fossil-scm.service.plist](http://pastebin.com/TAJdaZ3B)

Some explanation as to what is going on:

- /Library/LaunchDaemons/ is where the .plist files defining 'User
  Daemons' that are launched as system startup are kept. Some other
  useful locations: ~/Library/LaunchAgents for each user, and
  /Library/LaunchAgents for all users.
- KeepAlive
   Don't restart the service; this way of using fossil works by starting
  it in response to a request on port 8081.
- Label  org.fossil-scm.service
   names the service, so is can be started sudo launchctl load and
  stopped using sudo launchctl load
- ProgramArguments     
    /Users/spdegabrielle/bin/fossil
    http
    --localauth
    --notfound
    projects /Users/spdegabrielle/fossil-repository
    
   is the launchd way of saying 
   fossil http --localauth --notfound projects
  /Users/spdegabrielle/fossil-repository

The meanings of the arguments are as follows:

- fossil http action the
  request coming from port 8081(in this case), provide the response and
  quit. (see fossil help http)
- --localauth auto-sign-in if you are accessing fossil from your server directly with http://127.0.0.1:8081/ or http://localhost:8081/ (see fossil help http)
- --notfound projects
  sets the default repository when specifying the repository location as a folder (next)
  rather than as a specific repository
- /Users/spdegabrielle/fossil-repository is the respository location
  (--notfound projects sets the default)
- RunAtLoad - Don't run it on
  load - it will be run on demand
- inetdCompatibility causes launchd
  will behave like inetd for the launched program

Comment: I'd like a better way on including the plist file?